# How to extract frames from videos at a certain fps (ex. 15fps) using nvidia-dali?

Tags: video, frame, nvidia, video-processing

I have tried to follow the official documentation and examples of DALI. But i am at a loss to understand the meaning and use of the three following variables -

1. batch_size
2. sequence_length
3. n_iter

Official documentation link- https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/examples/sequence_processing/video/video_reader_simple_example.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question from the title, DALI loads all frames from the input video with default settings. If your video is recorded with 30 FPS, you can read it as 15 FPS by setting argument `stride=2` (DALI will skip every second frame).

To explain the meaning of the variables in the tutorial:

1. `batch_size`:
   DALI operators can run on GPU (when `device="gpu"` is set), and GPU is designed for parallel computation. The `batch_size` variable tells DALI how many videos to process in parallel.
2. `sequence_length`: tells how many frames DALI will include in the output.
3. `n_iter`: it is just for the tutorial. The loop in the example below will run the pipeline this many times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up. Lets suppose there is 100 videos of arbitrary length in a directory, that i want to process. All the frames in all the videos are labelled in a file. How can i do that using DALI?

Comment: How exactly are the frames labeled? Is it video matting, segmentation, or something else?
How is ground truth stored? Is there a video with labels for each input video?

Comment: Each frame within all the video is labeled by a single integer value, representing the classes in the domain. Such as, there are three classes, and all the frames are labeled with either 0/1/2. This labeling is stored within another file. Its not like that all the frames in a video have a video level labeling. Its more like frame level labeling for all the video.

Comment: Here is an example that uses the DALI PyTorch plugin: https://gist.github.com/mwawrzos/4ef080b79305429a495b6a10b614c118

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demo. I was working with keras. So consequently i searched for the DALIGenericIterator for tensorflow. But sadly i couldn't find it.

Comment: Here is a guide for Tensorflow, and there is an example for Keras: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/examples/frameworks/tensorflow/tensorflow-dataset.html
Combining those two examples should be straightforward.